# Segmentation fault OR Stacktrace when using UIView with message forwarding feature of Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

The problem: Given a class which just inherits from NSObject and has an instance of UIView wrapped. This class is named UIViewWrapper. I would like to use this UIViewWrapper with e.g. 'addSubview' of UIView. UIViewWrapper should act like a 'normal' UIView class.

I am currently utilizing the "message forwarding" feature of Objective-C to try to get things working. In 'addSubview' some calls are made to the instance of UIViewWrapper and up to a certain point those messages are forwarded correctly to the wrapped instance of UIView. But finally the program crashes either with a 'Segmentation fault: 11' (memory problems) or with a stacktrace (see below).

My questions: Is it possible to do something like this at all? If yes, is 'message forwarding' the best way to do it? If yes, what am I missing here? If no, what's a better approach to solve this kind of problem?

The code (omitting main.m and AppDelegate.h since they just have their usual contents):

```
//AppDelegate.m
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL) application : (UIApplication *) application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions : (NSDictionary *) launchOptions {
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame : [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

  //a normal UIView -> works as expected
  //UIView *theView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame : CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
  //[theView setBackgroundColor : [UIColor yellowColor]];

  //the wrapped version -> fails when added to the rootView
  UIViewWrapper *theView = [[UIViewWrapper alloc] init];

  UIView *rootView = [[UIView alloc] init];
  [rootView addSubview : theView];

  UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
  [rootViewController setView : rootView];

  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
  return YES;
}

//UIViewWrapper.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIViewWrapper : NSObject

@end

//UIViewWrapper.m
@interface UIViewWrapper()
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIView *uiview;

@end

@implementation UIViewWrapper

- (NSMethodSignature *) methodSignatureForSelector : (SEL) selector {
  return [UIView instanceMethodSignatureForSelector : selector];
}

-(void) forwardInvocation : (NSInvocation *) forwardedInvocation {
  if (!self.uiview) {
      self.uiview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame : CGRectMake(50, 50, 50, 50)];
      [self.uiview setBackgroundColor : [UIColor redColor]];
  }

  [forwardedInvocation invokeWithTarget : self.uiview];
}

@end
```

The important parts of the stacktrace which just appears sometimes. Any other time I get a segmentation fault: 11

```
Jan 27 13:55:09 Dirks-MacBook-Air Showcase[15741]: +[__NSBlockVariable__ superlayer]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2df82b4
Jan 27 13:55:09 Dirks-MacBook-Air Showcase[15741]: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[__NSBlockVariable__ superlayer]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2df82b4'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0253fa14 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x028a9e02 objc_exception_throw + 50
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x02548c03 +[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x024866bd ___forwarding___ + 1037
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0248628e _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   UIKit                               0x00dce092 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 1452
    6   UIKit                               0x00dbc8e4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) addSubview:] + 56
    7   Showcase                            0x001dcb4b -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 343
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you could clarify what are you trying to solve, we can help you more. I have a feeling that there's no point in finding solution for this and choosing a different approach would be better. As is often the case in Objective-C. You better stick to the "Cocoa way" of doing things.

Basically, now you're calling `addSubview` method with object of incorrect class as an argument. See picture #1. And that's the reason for crash.

[image: warning in xcode]

Comment: I know that this is completely incorrect and in a Java / C++ (and any other language with strong type checks) this wouldn't even compile. But since Objective-C and Cocoa is very dynamic I was curious if something 'weird' like this can be solved with language or framework features. UIViewWrapper is like a Proxy. The calling side should handle an instance of it like an UIView even if it is actually not. If one puts some NSLog-Statements into forwardInvocation one can see that some forwardings do very well but at one point it stops working. I wonder what's the exact reason.